# Passing contents of text file into Jsoup doesnt parse all the html

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

I have a text file "Data3.txt". This file contains lots of html.

I am passing this file into Jsoup so that all the html can be parsed using this example: "[Jsoup : How to parse multiple HTML files from local drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407402/jsoup-how-to-parse-multiple-html-files-from-local-drive)".

I am also printing out the contents of document to make sure it has all the html init.

However document contains only a small part of the html(the html,head,script,body tag). What am i doing wrong? how do i pass all the html

Here is my code:

```
public void stripContent() throws IOException{

   File f = new File("stripContentFile");
   BufferedWriter feedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));


    File input = new File("Data3.txt");
    try {
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document document = Jsoup.parse(input, null);
        System.out.println(document);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{

    }

}
```

My Data3.txt file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/83slaan4hmtzr9n/Data3.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The cause

It happens to you because `Jsoup.parse()` method by default uses [`Parser.htmlParser()`](http://%20Create%20a%20new%20HTML%20parser.%20This%20parser%20treats%20input%20as%20HTML5,%20and%20enforces%20the%20creation%20of%20a%20normalised%20document,%20based%20on%20a%20knowledge%20of%20the%20semantics%20of%20the%20incoming%20tags.). According to `Parser.htmlParser()` method documentation:

> Create a new HTML parser. This parser treats input as HTML5, and enforces the creation of a normalised document, based on a knowledge of the semantics of the incoming tags.

Your input file does not contain valid and strict HTML5. One of the requirements of valid and strict HTML5 code is to have all HTML tags lowercased. Tags in your input file are uppercased so they are skipped by the default parser.

### Solution

There are two things you can do:

1. Correct the input file so it is HTML5 complaint.
2. Use [`Parser.xmlParser()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html#xmlParser--) instead, e.g. with following method:

   ```
   Document document = Jsoup.parse(InputStream in, String charsetName, String baseUri, Parser parser);
   ```

   https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse-java.io.InputStream-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.jsoup.parser.Parser-

   XmlParser treats every tag as a correct one so you have to be aware that switching to XmlParser means that your HTML code wont be validated by the parser. It is meant to be used with a XML files, but it may help you solving your problem.

   Of course it requires using `InputStream` instead of `File`, but can easily convert one to another e.g. `new FileInputStream(new File("Data3.txt"))`

Comment: I'm glad I could help you :)